# GeoPandas in ArcGIS Pro not updating operation performed

Tags: python, arcgis-pro, geopandas, numpy, pandas

I am new in the programming area. I have done some code making use of sources on the web. That is why I am having trouble. In my query I have used GeoPandas, Pandas and numpy library to make modifications in the table of a Feature class. When I run the code it performs the operation I wrote but when I check the FC in ArcGIS Pro it does not change.

Code:

```py
capa_feature1 = gpd.read_file(r"D:\Proj_ASEAN\Proj_ArcGIS\Proj_ASEAN\SMOD.gdb")
operacion = lambda x,y,z: (x - y -z)
capa_feature1['SUM_Area_km2'] = np.where( capa_feature1['Area_km2'] == capa_feature1.iat[0,4], capa_feature1.iat[0,4], operacion(capa_feature1.iat[0,5],capa_feature1.iat[0,4],capa_feature1.iat[1,4]))
capa_feature1
```

This is the code that I made. Why are no changes shown in the attribute table of the feature class?

Comment: Are you writing the operation back to the .gdb file you're loading?

Comment: You're not actually attempting to make any modifications. Given that you're using Pro, using AddField (if necessary) and CalculateField with a `!shape!.getArea(...)` with appropriate parameters for the spatial reference is likely to be much more effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Esri Community forum](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/i-use-the-geopandas-in-arcgis-pro-and-it-does-not/m-p/1217660#M60553):

> You're reading the data in to a GeoDataFrame (gdf) which is in memory
> and no longer connected to the file geodatabase (FileGDB) FeatureClass
> (fc), so changing the gdf will not change the fc.
>
> You need to write the gdf back to the FileGDB and overwrite the fc.
>
> However, the OpenFileGDB driver that GeoPandas uses is read-only
> (unless you install the Esri FileGDB API and driver which can be
> difficult) so you are better off either using:
>
> - ArcGIS methods (field calculator or `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`) to do your calculation, or
> - [writing out a different format](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/io.html#writing-spatial-data) (like a geopackage or geojson) and then using ArcGIS to import that to your FileGDB

Comment: Thank's so much